# My list is not updating in one of my scripts but is in the other

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

My first script is creating a list of string and updates every time there is a collision between my player or gameObject called pacman_1. here is the code:

```
public class Node : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<string> FinalPath = new List<string>();
    public static GameObject PlayerPos, EnemyPos;
    public static string SPlayerPos, SEnemyPos;
    public static bool E, P;
    // Use this for initialization

    void Start()
    {
        var box = gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        box.isTrigger = enabled;


    private void Update()
    {

    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.name == "pacman_1")
        {   
            SEnemyPos = EnemyPos.name
            E = true;

        }

        if (other.name == "player")
        {

            SPlayerPos = PlayerPos.name;
            P = true;
        }


        if (P == true || E == true)
        {

            Graph g = new Graph();
            g.add_vertex("P1", new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "P41", 3 }, { "P49", 2 } });

            /***********************************/
            /**** 62 vertices omitted -- ed ****/
            /***********************************/

            g.add_vertex("P64", new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "P34", 3 }, { "P44", 2 } });

            g.shortest_path(SPlayerPos, SEnemyPos).ForEach(x => FinalPath.Add(x));

            E = false;
            P = false;

        }
    }
}

public class Graph
{
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> vertices = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
    public void add_vertex(string name, Dictionary<string, int> edges)
    {
        vertices[name] = edges;
    }
    public List<string> shortest_path(string start, string finish)
    {
        var previous = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var distances = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        var nodes = new List<string>(); 
        List<string> path = null;
        foreach (var vertex in vertices)
        {
            if (vertex.Key == start)
            {
                distances[vertex.Key] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                distances[vertex.Key] = int.MaxValue;
            }

            nodes.Add(vertex.Key);
        }

        while (nodes.Count != 0)
        {
            nodes.Sort((x, y) => distances[x] - distances[y]);

            var smallest = nodes[0];
            nodes.Remove(smallest);

            if (smallest == finish)
            {
                path = new List<string>();
                while (previous.ContainsKey(smallest))
                {
                    path.Add(smallest);
                    smallest = previous[smallest];
                }

                break;
            }

            if (distances[smallest] == int.MaxValue)
            {
                break;
            }

            foreach (var neighbor in vertices[smallest])
            {
                var alt = distances[smallest] + neighbor.Value;
                if (alt < distances[neighbor.Key])
                {
                    distances[neighbor.Key] = alt;
                    previous[neighbor.Key] = smallest;
                }
            }
        }
        path.Add(start);
        return path;
    }
}
```

then this is my other script that is accessing the list correctly the first time but is staying the same after that:

```
public class enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<GameObject> finP = new List<GameObject>();
    public Node nodeScript;
    public float Speed = 1.0f;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        nodeScript = GameObject.Find("P16").GetComponent<Node>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        MovePosition();
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "pallet" && nodeScript.FinalPath.Count>1)
        {

            finP.Clear();
            foreach(string var in nodeScript.FinalPath)
            {
                finP.Add(GameObject.Find(var));
            }
        }
    }

    void MovePosition()
    {
        if (finP.Count < 1) return;
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, finP[1].transform.localPosition, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

this is the original list outputted as intended in my console:
[screen shot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxwtu.png)

then this is the list updating in one script and it not in the other:

[another screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxwtu.png)

Comment: Can you remove all of the unnecessary code?  it will be much less intimidating to look at if you removed all of your commented out code, and extra white-space.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thats fine, but I have seen users get beat up for leaving in commented out code as well.

Comment: @Eddge That's certainly the case, and that's part of why I made a point of bringing it up in the comments here.

Comment: ill do it now sorry was keeping the commented code so i can show how my code has changed over time to my teacher

Comment: @EdPlunkett yea you were trying to help me before. i was just asking for general thinks like where does this commonly happen but re-posted because the code was needed

Comment: @TomUnsworth Well Firstly your image URLs are both the same image, so that's a bit unclear. Secondly have you noticed your enemy class uses `GameObject.Find("P16")` always, maybe that is intended? Thirdly your code is a bit unclear, you show a screenshot with `Debug.Log` statements, however I never saw one in your code, so I have no idea where to imagine it would be.

Comment: sorry i removed all the code that wasn't needed for it to run. i was debug.logging the items in final path from the enemy script, just to show that when the finalpath is changed in my node script it doesn't change in my enemy script.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `List<string> FinalPath` that you want to update? If so, try initializing it in the Start() function like this:

```
void Start(){

      FinalPath = new List<string>();
}
```

I don't know for sure, but I think lists cannot be initialized outside of a method.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it just gave me the same output.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few areas I would look at to see if they are conflicting with the intended outcome of your scripts.

```
nodeScript = GameObject.Find("P16").GetComponent<Node>();
```

This is getting the `Node` component on the `GameObject` with the name 'P16', so the `nodeScript.FinalPath` call will only reference that node. Is this intended? Could it be that the 'P16' node is only recieving a certain number of collisions.

```
nodeScript.FinalPath.Count>1
```

This returns true when there are at least two elements in the list; did you intend a `> 0` operation?

```
foreach(string var in nodeScript.FinalPath)
{
    finP.Add(GameObject.Find(var));
}
```

`var` is a keyword in C#, I would avoid using it as a variable name. Though it appears to compile OK.

Comment: i think it must be because it be that it only works if the enemy has collided with that gameobject that is being used to link the two scripts (P16 in this case) because i  changed it it "P1" and the final path isnt accessed in the enemy script.

Comment: the nodeScript .FinalPath.count < 0 was so it wouldn't run if the path hasn't been sent over yet, because i was having issues with the path not being found in time and the enemy was trying to follow a path that didn't exist